# Using hook_form_alter to enter placeholder in mailchimp signup fom

Tags: 7, forms

For the signup form I'm using the Mailchimp Signup module. The idea is to hide the label, which I did using the `unset();` function, and put an a placeholder in the input field where people enter their emailaddress.

Here's the code:

```
function bw_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

  if ($form_id == 'mailchimp_signup_subscribe_block_mysite_group_form') {
    //dpm($form);
    unset( $form['mergevars']['EMAIL']['#title']);
    $form['mergevars']['EMAIL']['#placeholder'] = t('Your emailaddress');
    dpm($form['mergevars']['EMAIL']['#placeholder']);
    }
}
```

`dpm($form['mergevars']['EMAIL']['#placeholder']);` returns the string `Your emailaddress` nicely in the green drupal message frame. Yet, the actual placeholder isn't there in my input element. Looking at the attributes of the particular `input`field in question, the attribute isn't added either:

```
<input id="edit-mergevars-email" class="form-text required" type="text" maxlength="128" size="25" value="" name="mergevars[EMAIL]">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
$form['mergevars']['EMAIL']['#attributes'] = array(
 'placeholder'=> t('Your placeholder'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all field titles as placeholders:

```
$key_blacklist = array('#prefix','#suffix','#tree');

foreach($form['mergevars'] as $key => $var) {
  if ( ! in_array($key, $key_blacklist)) {
    $form['mergevars'][$key]['#attributes'] = array( 'placeholder'=> $form['mergevars'][$key]['#title']);
  }
}
```